# How to union a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, optimization, coding-style

I wrote this program to calculate the 3d distance for a group of points.

```
points = [(472765.09, 6191522.78, 13.0), (472764.82, 6191524.09, 9.0), (472763.8, 6191525.68, 8.0), (472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)]

def dist3d((x0, y0, z0), (x1, y1, z1)):
    return math.sqrt((x0-x1)**2+(y0-y1)**2+(z0-z1)**2)

def dist_3d(obs):
    dist_list = list()
    while len(obs) != 1:
        obs_g = [(obs[0], x) for x in obs[1:]]
        dist_list.append([dist3d(obs_g[i][0], obs_g[i][1]) for i in xrange(len(obs_g))])
        obs.pop(0)
    return dist_list
```

The result is a list of distance lists:

```
test = dist_3d(points)
print test
[[4.217700795331081, 5.922339064664832, 3.554222840244929], [2.1374049685457694, 7.046453008421205], [8.107835716151763]]
```

The result I wish to have is the following:

```
[4.217700795331081, 5.922339064664832, 3.554222840244929, 2.1374049685457694, 7.046453008421205, 8.107835716151763]
```

P.S.: the code is not optimized because the "`points`" list after the function returns with only one element

```
points = [(472765.09, 6191522.78, 13.0), (472764.82, 6191524.09, 9.0), (472763.8, 6191525.68, 8.0), (472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)]
test = dist_3d(points)
points
[(472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your first problem, use `list.extend` on this line:

```
dist_list.append([dist3d(obs_g[i][0], obs_g[i][1]) for i in xrange(len(obs_g))])
```

as in:

```
          ######
dist_list.extend([dist3d(obs_g[i][0], obs_g[i][1]) for i in xrange(len(obs_g))])
          ######
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/2555451) is a demonstration of why that will help.

---

Your second problem comes from this line:

```
obs.pop(0)
```

Because `obs` and `points` both reference the same list object, calling `obs.pop` is the same as calling `points.pop` directly. In other words, each time that line is executed, an item is popped from `points`.  In the end, this will cause `points` to contain only one item.

To fix this problem, make a shallow copy of `points` inside `dist_3d`:

```
copy = obs[:]
```

Then, call `pop` on the copy.  Doing so will leave `points` unaffected.

---

Below is how the modified code will look:

```
import math

points = [(472765.09, 6191522.78, 13.0), (472764.82, 6191524.09, 9.0), (472763.8, 6191525.68, 8.0), (472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)]

def dist3d((x0, y0, z0), (x1, y1, z1)):
    return math.sqrt((x0-x1)**2+(y0-y1)**2+(z0-z1)**2)

def dist_3d(obs):
    dist_list = list()
    copy = obs[:]
    while len(copy) != 1:
        obs_g = [(copy[0], x) for x in copy[1:]]
        dist_list.extend([dist3d(obs_g[i][0], obs_g[i][1]) for i in xrange(len(obs_g))])
        copy.pop(0)
    return dist_list
```

And here is a sample run:

```
>>> import math
>>> points = [(472765.09, 6191522.78, 13.0), (472764.82, 6191524.09, 9.0), (472763.8, 6191525.68, 8.0), (472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)]
>>> def dist3d((x0, y0, z0), (x1, y1, z1)):
...     return math.sqrt((x0-x1)**2+(y0-y1)**2+(z0-z1)**2)
...
>>> def dist_3d(obs):
...     dist_list = list()
...     copy = obs[:]
...     while len(copy) != 1:
...         obs_g = [(copy[0], x) for x in copy[1:]]
...         dist_list.extend([dist3d(obs_g[i][0], obs_g[i][1]) for i in xrange(len(obs_g))])
...         copy.pop(0)
...     return dist_list
...
>>> test = dist_3d(points)
>>> print test
[4.217700795331081, 5.922339064664832, 3.554222840244929, 2.1374049685457694, 7.046453008421205, 8.107835716151763]
>>> print points
[(472765.09, 6191522.78, 13.0), (472764.82, 6191524.09, 9.0), (472763.8, 6191525.68, 8.0), (472764.07, 6191524.39, 16.0)]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks ICodez. The problem of one element in test persist. See the update in the post

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def dist_3d(obs):
    dist_list = list()
    while len(obs) != 1:
        obs_g = [(obs[0], x) for x in obs[1:]]
        dist_list.append([dist3d(obs_g[i][0], obs_g[i][1]) for i in xrange(len(obs_g))])
        obs.pop(0)
    return list(itertools.chain(*dist_list))
```